# equivalent to showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, showmodaldialog

I have a webapplication which have call to showModalDialog but due to some reason this is not supported by chrome and I did search on for a work around but without any success.

The showModalDialog displays a aspx page with search field and a grid will be displayed with all the depts when user select on any deptname link the name should display in paren window textbox.

```
function DisplayDept() 
{
    var Object = window.showModalDialog('../DeptList.aspx', null, 'location=0,center:yes,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=500');
    if (Object != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("<%=hdnDept.ClientID%>").value = Object.id;
        if(document.getElementById("<%=txtDname.ClientID%>").value!=Object.name)
        {
            document.getElementById("<%=txtDname.ClientID%>").value=Object.name;
            __doPostBack(document.getElementById("<%=txtDname.ClientID%>").name,''); 
        }
     }
}

 function LinkSelected(intCD, strName)
    {
         var obj=new Object();
         obj.id=intCD;
        obj.name=strName;
        window.returnValue = obj;
        window.close();
    }
```

Tried with window.open method but unable to assing the selected field from open window to parent window control, wondering what would be ideal solution for this as I ma using asp.net web. application. Any suggestin/help on this would be of gr8 help.

Comment: From the Mozilla website: “This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.” https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog

Comment: Is it a good practise to open the aspx page using jQueryUI Dialog if not please suggest some alternate.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have resolved using windows.open as below.

```
function DisplayDept() 
{
    var Object = window.open('../DeptList.aspx', null, 'location=0,center:yes,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=500');
 }
```

followed by

```
function SetDept(Object) {
       if (Object != null)
      {
            document.getElementById("<%=txtDname.ClientID%>").value=Object.name;
            __doPostBack(document.getElementById("<%=txtDname.ClientID%>").name,''); 
        }

    }
```

And in the child windows

```
function SelectIt(intTypeCD, strTypeName)
    {
        var obj=new Object();
         obj.id=intCD;
        obj.name=strName;
         window.opener.SetDept(obj);
        window.close();
    }
```